# Automated two column in a text

Tags: conditionals, two-column, multicolumn, page

I write multiple single page documents. The sentences consist of mostly itemised  list . When the written text exceed a page length and flows into another, I convert them to two columns by changing preamble. This involves going back to source after compiling document every time. I can use two column as default settings for all the documents, but for a short document which fits into single column, it looks odd.
Is there a way I can automate this? Whenever the document length exceeds page length, it should change to two columns instead of one .

This is MWE

```
  % Created 2019-01-21 Mon 11:20
% Intended LaTeX compiler: xelatex
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{grffile}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{capt-of}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\pagenumbering{}
\usepackage[a4paper, top=42mm, right=2cm, bottom=1.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{fontspec,xltxtra}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\usepackage[Latin,Devanagari]{ucharclasses}
\setmainfont{Arial Unicode MS}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\author{Me}
\date{\today}
\title{}
\hypersetup{
 pdfauthor={Me},
 pdftitle={},
 pdfkeywords={},
 pdfsubject={},
 pdfcreator={Emacs 25.3.1 (Org mode 9.1.14)}, 
 pdflang={English}}
\begin{document}

Mr X Y Z 

DOB XX XX 196X

Phone 982640xxxx


\today 


\section*{Past History}
\label{sec:orgdd28594}
\begin{itemize}
\item Idiopathic ulcerative colitis (proctosigmoiditis) 2013
\end{itemize}
\section*{Follow up}
\label{sec:orgb1e6798}
Stool frequency of 4-6 per day, Painful. Bleeding separate from stools. 
Bloating of abdomen 
There is no weight loss. 
\section*{Examination}
\label{sec:org1fd6fb7}
No abnormality detected 
\section*{Investigations}
\label{sec:org168a269}
Complete blood count , Random blood sugar, sigmoidoscopy 
SCHEDULED: \textit{<2019-01-23 Wed> } 

\section*{Rx}
\label{sec:org0d9debc}
\begin{enumerate}
\item TAB VEGAZ  OD (MESALAMIN) 1.2 GM   TWICE DAILY (दिन में 2 बार)  AFTER MEALS (खाने के बाद)   X  Long term
\item TAB FOLVITE (FOLIC ACID) 5 MG  ONCE DAILY (दिन में 1 बार )1-0-0-0 X LONG TERM
\item CREMAGEL (DILTIAZEM)  aply at anus after seitz bath twice daily (दिन में 2 बार) 1-0-1-0 x 15 days
\item TORBULK /LACTIFIBER 180 GM दो चम्मच पावडर  एक  गिलास पानी में डाल कर शाम को ले  (सोते समय)   0-0-0-1 X 15 days
\item TAB CROCIN (PARACETAMOL) 500 MG 1 TABLET   as and when needed (जब जरुरत हो तो दवा ले ) FOR FEVER OR PAIN
\item LIGNOX (LIGNOCAIN) GEL before and after defecation if severe anal pain
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Do you use any sectional units or references within the document?

Comment: @Werner added MWE

Answer (score 1):

Your example doesn't show any use of referencing or sectional units that are numbered. Additionally, there's no explicit use of [`hyperref`](//ctan.org/pkg/hyperref). So, below I've removed those elements.

Finally, the layout of the content is very different for a one-column and two-column layout. Take, for example, the initial "tombstone" information. It's predominantly contained within the left half of a one-column document. If there's a need to switch to a two-column document, the right side of that upper portion is suddenly being utilized which, for documents that just barely rolls over to two pages, switching to a two-column layout could make it fit onto a single page.

The main approach of this solution is to wrap the entire document content into a `oneortwocolumn` macro.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xparse}% Unless you have an updated LaTeX (as of Oct 2020)

\newsavebox{\ONEorTWOcol}
\NewDocumentCommand{\oneortwocolumn}{s +m}{%
  \IfBooleanTF{#1}{%
    #2%
  }{%
    % Store the entire document in a box that one can extract measurements from
    \begin{lrbox}{\ONEorTWOcol}%
      \begin{minipage}[b]{\textwidth}
        #2%
      \end{minipage}
    \end{lrbox}
    
    % Check if box is taller than \textheight
    \ifdim\ht\ONEorTWOcol>\textheight
      % If so, reset the entire document in a two-column document
      \begin{multicols}{2}
        #2%
      \end{multicols}
    \else
      % Otherwise, reset it in its original form
      #2%
    \fi
  }
}

\usepackage{multicol,lipsum}
\usepackage[a4paper, top=42mm, right=2cm, bottom=1.5cm]{geometry}

\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}

\begin{document}

\oneortwocolumn{

Mr Random Randofsky

DOB 01-23-4567

Phone 123-456-7890

\today

\section*{Past History}
\begin{itemize}
  \item Idiopathic ulcerative colitis (proctosigmoiditis) 2013
\end{itemize}

\section*{Follow up}
Stool frequency of 4-6 per day, Painful. Bleeding separate from stools.
Bloating of abdomen.
There is no weight loss.

\section*{Examination}
No abnormality detected

\section*{Investigations}
Complete blood count, Random blood sugar, sigmoidoscopy
SCHEDULED: 2019-01-23 Wed

% Check with \lipsum[1-5], which will be set in two-column mode on 1 page
\lipsum[1-10]

\section*{Rx}
\begin{enumerate}
  \item First item
  \item Second item
  \item Third item
  \item Fourth item
  \item Fifth item
  \item Final item
\end{enumerate}

}

\end{document}
```

If you switch the random text to `\lipsum[1-5]`, you'll find it sets the page in two columns on a single page. That's because of the lost "tombstone" space suddenly being occupied under the two-column setup. If this switch results into an undesirable setup, use the starred form of `\oneortwocolumn*`, which will force the output into a single-column layout.

The approach can be extended to accommodate for `\ref`erences, if needed.

Comment: I use Emacs org to export latex. Is it possible to get away without putting parentheses {} around text?

Comment: @Vaibhav: One could rewrite the code to use an environment rather than a macro. So you'd write `\begin{oneortwocolumn}`...`\end{oneortwocolumn}`. However, if you wish to have a similar `oneortwocolumn*` environment to force (say) one column, then you'll have to change it in two locations (at the `\begin` and `\end`).